# What is the difference between a "decorator function" and "decorator design pattern" in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, function, object, decorator

It seems like in JavaScript functions which take in a function, modify behavior and return that function are decorators. For example, this would be a decorator function:

```
function doubleDec (func){
    return function(){
        return 2*func.apply(this, arguments)
    }
}
function sum(a, b) {
  return a + b
}

var doubleSum = doubleDec(sum)

alert(doubleSum(1,2))  //=> 6
```

But a decorator design pattern means you are taking in an object ...and modifying it?

Comment: You can read about decorator pattern in JS here: http://addyosmani.com/resources/essentialjsdesignpatterns/book/#decoratorpatternjavascript

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Decorators are a generic pattern; it can mean multiple things depending on the domain.

They're also called "wrappers" or "adapters", which IMO is more applicable to the function wrapping paradigm. That said, don't get too hung up on precise wording: they're *patterns*, not immutable laws.

Comment: Are you sure decorators are called adapters? Adapters change something into something else so that it can be used in different context. Decorators doesn't change, the decorated object can be used in the very same context where the original object is used.

Comment: @WiktorZychla Yes, I am. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decorator_pattern, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adapter_pattern. I'll make the same point again: be careful when discussing *general patterns* vs *specific implementations*.

Comment: What I just read there is that decorators are sometimes called wrappers and adapters are also called wrappers ("naming shared with adapter"). There is no indication that decorators are also called adapters.

Comment: @WiktorZychla "decorator pattern (also known as Wrapper, an alternative naming shared with the Adapter pattern)", and "adapter pattern (often referred to as the wrapper pattern or simply a wrapper - an alternative naming shared with the Decorator pattern according to the GoF Design Patterns book)", and the same point, yet again.

Comment: @DaveNetwon: if you, Dave, are sometimes called Bob and I, Wiktor, am sometimes called Bob, it doesn't mean that you, Dave, are sometimes called Wiktor. I am not against your answer but I would never call "decorator" an "adapter". This would lead to unnecessary confusion. On the other hand, calling decorator "a wrapper" and calling adapter "a wrapper" is ok.

Comment: @WiktorZychla Not analogous, and it should be obvious. If an adapter may be a wrapper, and a wrapper may be an adapter, and a decorator may be called either *one* of those, then it may be called the other. And it's nonsensical on the face of it: a decorator can most *certainly* adapt, because "to adapt" is about as generic a term as is possible. You'll have to continue this one without me.

Comment: Clarification: My question was not whether decorators were wrappers or adapters. I was trying to understand if there was a reason why a decorator function and decorator design pattern shared the word decorator. It would be helpful if someone could explain what the "generic design pattern" of a decorator is.

Comment: @Gina It adds/alters functionality to/on whatever is being decorated. A decorator function alters/adds the function it's wrapping. A decorator object alters/adds the object it's decorating. They share the word "decorator" because they do the same thing, in different ways, and the distinction isn't meaningful.